# how to detect change and prevent form submitting in GSP/ HTML using jquery/javascript if there is no change detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gsp

I want to block my form submission if there is no change in fields.
My code looks like this:

```
    <g:form >
       <label for="contactPersonName">
          <g:message code="vendorGeneralAddress.contactPersonName.label" default="Contact Person Name" />
          <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
       </label>
       <g:textField tabindex="1" placeholder="${g.message(code:'vendorGeneralAddress.contactPersonName.label')}" name="contactPersonName" value="${vendorGeneralAddressInstance?.contact_person_name}"/>

       <label for="city">
          <g:message code="vendorGeneralAddress.city.label" default="City" />
          <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
       </label>
       <g:textField tabindex="5" placeholder="${g.message(code:'vendorGeneralAddress.city.label')}" name="city" value="${vendorGeneralAddressInstance?.city}"/>

       <g:actionSubmit name="change" controller ="c1" action="g1" value="${message(code: 'bv.change.request.customer', default: 'Change')}"/>
       <g:actionSubmit name="create" controller ="c1" action="g2" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}"/>

     </g:form>
```

Comment: Seems like you are using  Grails Framework. you can check the features available in Grails Framwork (like dirty checks in angularjs) and take the next action or alternately, If you want to do it manually, then  you can simply set dirty flag on off  in controller if concern filed in the text box changes its values and make the decision.

Comment: @Mukund Kamble thanks for your suggestion